How can I refresh a token while working with msal-node for Microsoft Integration?
I'm using @azure/msal library along with Microsoft Graph api's. Also please note that I'm working with a Confidential Client Application. I have the first flow all set and done, I get the access token through:
cca.acquireTokenByCode().
Now the token generated has an expiry of 1 hour. I need a mechanism to refresh that access token. I have tried some ways to get the refresh token but I have failed to get any successful response.
1- I tried with getting the token cache and then getting the RefreshToken property that contains the secret but passing that to acquireTokenByRefreshToken() does nothing. get an error of bad_token.
2- I tried with cca.getTokenCache().getAccountByHomeId(), passing the accountId to this function but I'm getting the account as null. However, I checked that the home account id is exactly the same as I have in the response but still gives me null. Looks like it clears the cache or something.
3- The third approach was to use a persistent cache so I tried to get it done with Node cache but still the same. The account is null.
I'm trying to get the account so that I can send that to the cca.acquireTokenSilent() function.
Need any help with that.
I tried to first get the Refresh token and send that to the acquireTokenByRefreshToken() funtion, but I'm receiving a bad_token error.
Also I tried to get it done by fetching the account by the homeAccountId but the account is null. I was expecting to get the account so that I can send that to acquireTokenSilent() function. I'm not sure if that clears the cache or not.

I tried the below code to get the refresh token from Azure Active Directory.
Code :
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const authUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
const tokenUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token';
const clientId = '<client_ID>';
const clientSecret = '<client_secret>';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/callback'; 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const scope = encodeURIComponent(clientId + '/.default') + encodeURIComponent(' offline_access');
  const authorizationUrl = `${authUrl}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=code&scope=${scope}`;
  res.send(`Authorization URL: <a href="${authorizationUrl}">${authorizationUrl}</a>`);
});
app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => { 
  const { code } = req.query;
  const tokenParams = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    scope: clientId + '/.default offline_access'
  };
  try {
    const tokenResponse = await axios.post(tokenUrl, querystring.stringify(tokenParams), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    });
    const refreshToken = tokenResponse.data.refresh_token;
    res.send(`Refresh Token: ${refreshToken}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error exchanging authorization code for tokens:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error exchanging authorization code for tokens');
  }
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

I added the below URL's in the Azure AD app as a Single-page application and Web application as below,
http://localhost:3000/


http://localhost:3000/callback


Output :

Browser output :
I got below in the browser and clicked on the Authorization URL as below,

It redirects me to select my account for login as below,

I got the refresh token as shown below.

Then, I set the expiration time for the access token in the below code.
setTimeout(refreshAccessToken,  (expiresIn -  300)  *  1000);

const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const authUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
const tokenUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token';
const clientId = '<client_ID>';
const clientSecret = '<client_secret>';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/callback'; 

let accessToken = null;
let refreshToken = null;

async function refreshAccessToken() {
  try {
    const tokenParams = {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_id: clientId,
      client_secret: clientSecret,
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
      redirect_uri: redirectUri
    };

    const tokenResponse = await axios.post(tokenUrl, querystring.stringify(tokenParams), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    });
    accessToken = tokenResponse.data.access_token;
    refreshToken = tokenResponse.data.refresh_token;
    const expiresIn = tokenResponse.data.expires_in;
    setTimeout(refreshAccessToken, (expiresIn - 300) * 1000); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error refreshing access token:', error);
  }
}
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const scope = encodeURIComponent(clientId + '/.default');
  const authorizationUrl = `${authUrl}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=code&scope=${scope}`;
  res.send(`Authorization URL: <a href="${authorizationUrl}">${authorizationUrl}</a>`);
});
app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => { 
  const { code } = req.query;
  const tokenParams = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri
  };
  try {
    const tokenResponse = await axios.post(tokenUrl, querystring.stringify(tokenParams), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    });
    accessToken = tokenResponse.data.access_token;
    refreshToken = tokenResponse.data.refresh_token;
    const expiresIn = tokenResponse.data.expires_in;
    setTimeout(refreshAccessToken, (expiresIn - 300) * 1000); 

    res.send(`Access Token: ${accessToken}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error exchanging authorization code for access token:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error exchanging authorization code for access token');
  }
});
app.get('/current-access-token', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Current Access Token: ${accessToken}`);
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Output :

Browser Output :
I got below in the browser and clicked on Authorization URL as below,

I got the access token after successful login as below.


Have you tried the solution I provided?

That looks like a lot of work to get a refresh token - is there a simpler way?   (much respect to you for putting in the effort to post that though )
